# Modelling uml diagrams Use case -> Sequence?

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

After having my use case diagrams,  i can't found the logique to follow to implement the [sequence diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm), how can i go from analysis the what to design the how from the actors and uses cases to a sequence diagram with many stereotype without thinking about the class diagram (to respect the order).
Or should i have to implement others diagrams to passe from the use case one to the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always created class diagrams and sequence diagrams together (and, at least, the UML modeller Sparx Enterprise Architect is compatible with that point of view), but I was never educated in the `proper order` if such a thing exist.

Comment: Agree, there is also more to Usecase Analysis than just producing the use case diagram, that is only the first step.  The next would be to product Usecase Document, using something such as http://www.bredemeyer.com/pdf_files/use_case.pdf